# Render (and validate) related choice form fields in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to work out the best way to implement a form in django that has two choice fields on it, one of which affects the choices available in the other. An example - form field one is a radio button (can choose only one option) called 'cuisine', and the second is a multichoice field called 'menu'. If you choose 'french' from 'cuisine' then you get french dishes in the menu list, but if you choose 'chinese' you get a different selection.

How do I work this server-side in the form validation process. How do I 'bind' the two controls so that only dishes related to the cuisine option are accepted?

And how do I render this - should I pass in a ModelForm for each type of cuisine, or have a single menu ModelForm that has everything in it, and just show/hide stuff on the client-side?

All of the menu options are stored in the db and loaded in as fixtures, and the cuisines are hard-coded into the app:

```
CUISINE = ((0,'French'),(1,'Chinese'),(2,'Italian'))

class MenuItem(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cuisine = models.IntegerField('Cuisine', choices=CUISINE)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **For rendering**, you can use [django-selectable](http://django-selectable.readthedocs.org/en/version-0.5.2/advanced.html#chained-selection) or [django-autocomplete-light](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependant.html),
2. **For server side validation**, django has it [completely documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).